# read int per line c++ error needs solution

Tags: c++

hey guys I need help for my read code seems not working properly here's the code. The problem is as shown in the picture, the compiler are supposed to display all 1 million int value but it seems that my write or the display code was wrong. It shows nothing like it's not even reading. 
[image]
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int* CreateArray( int*);
void shellSortParallel( int*, int);
void shellSortSequential(int*, int);
void InsertSort( int*, int, int, int);

int main()
{
int array_size = 1000000;
int n=0;
int* arr=new int[array_size];
ifstream fin("OUTPUT1.txt");
if(! fin)
    {
cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }
else
    {
cout << "File Opened successfully!!!. Reading data from file into array" << endl;
        int data;   
        while(fin>>data)
        {
            arr[n] = data;
            n++;
        }
    cout << "Displaying Array..." << endl << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
}
fin.close();
int length = 1000000;
double endTime = 0, startTime = 0, totalTime = 0;
double start, end;
cout << "Program is now sorting using shell sort" <<endl;
startTime = time(NULL);
start = omp_get_wtime();// Start performance timer 1 run
shellSortParallel(arr, length);//Run the algorithm
end = omp_get_wtime();// End performance timer 1 run
endTime = time(NULL);
totalTime = endTime - startTime;
cout << "This is the time it took to run.  " << totalTime << endl;// time in seconds
int stupid = 0;
cin >> stupid;
cout << "Program has completed all tasks!!" << endl;
return 0;
}

void shellSortParallel(int array[], int length)
{
int h;
int j = 0;
int temp = 0;
int i = 0;
    for(h =length/2; h > 0; h = h/2)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for shared( array, length, h, i)  default(none)
        for( i = 0; i < h; i++)
        {
            //int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
            InsertSort(array, i, length, h);
        }
    }
}

void InsertSort(int arr[], int i, int length,  int half)
{   
//cout << ID << "   ";
int temp = 0;
int j = 0;
    for (int f = half + i; f < length; f = f + half)
    {
        j = f;
        while(j > i && arr[j-half] > arr[j])
        {
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j-half];
            arr[j-half] = temp;
            j = j -half;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the short version of the file that I'm going to read. Its a random number between 1 to 1million per line

```
2377763
88764877846
281327
60
625
86
646127818
14551
2177645
32033
1826761
555173
3415445377
32430
1101
```

any help would be much appreciate, thank you before

Comment: Please fix your code. All that double spacing, wherever it came from, is unacceptable.

Comment: what is this `arr[n-1] = '\0';`? it's not an array of characters

Comment: a `32 bit` int can't hold this value `88764877846`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr[n-1] = '\0';` is not correct because it's not an array of character so don't mind.

to correct it:

```
int data;   
while(fin>>data)
{
    arr[n] = data;
    n++;
}

cout << "Displaying Array..." << endl << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i];
}
```

- why allocating such huge array of integers? use vector is a good thing:

  ```
  vector<int> vec;
  ifstream fin("OUTPUT1.txt");
  int data;   
  while(fin >> data)
  {
      vec.push_back(data);
  }

  cout << "Displaying Array..." << endl << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
      cout << vec[i] << endl;
  fin.close();
  ```
- `88764877846` out band of an integer which causes the loop stop reading so you have to either get values as strings then convert into `__int64` or `__int128`

to read values as strings:

```
    string sLine;
    int nLines = 0;
    ifstream fin("OUTPUT1.txt");

    // first read to get number of lines
    while(getline(fin, sLine))
        nLines++;

    //create an array of strings
    string* pstrValues = new string[nLines];

    // set the get pointer to the beginning of file because the previous read moved it
    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    int i = 0;

    while(getline(fin, sLine))
    {
        pstrValues[i] = sLine;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "Displaying Array..." << endl << endl;
    for( i = 0; i < nLines; i++)
        cout << pstrValues[i] << endl;
    fin.close();
```

- now you have an array of strings convert it to int values but you must convert to `__int64` because as I said there are values bigger than size of `int` (4bytes)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, now it's showing a bunch of zero. Thank you for the tips though :)

Comment: i add second picture so you can see

Comment: I never tried using vector still a beginner. Thanks for the concept I will try it :D

Comment: how do I convert the vector to the void shell sort Parallel and void insertion sort?

Answer (score 1):

By `if(fin>>data)` you are not just testing, but retrieving data from stream. I suggest use ifs.good() for testing. Overall, you can write such a code instead

```
std::ifstream fin ("OUTPUT1.txt", std::ifstream::in);
char c = fin.get();

while (fin.good()) 
{
   std::cout << c;
   c = fin.get();
}
```